# Enquiry on an integral problem

Tags: integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

What is

$$\int  \ln (0.25+ x^2) \mathrm{d}x ?$$  Too bad am not yet very familiar with Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Yeah...  What about taking $z=0.25+x^2$ ?

Comment: By the way, the input is `int log(0.25 + x^2)`.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**$$\int1.\log\left(\frac14+x^2\right)\,\mathrm dx=x\log\left(\frac14+x^2\right)-\int\frac{2x^2}{\frac14+x^2}\,\mathrm dx.$$

Comment: Thanks !, the last integral can then be easily evaluated by noticing that $2x^{2}=2(0.25 + x^2 )-0.5$.

Comment: @Isaac. Indeed.